# How to display OWASP's Dependency Check Maven results for several project in one dashboard

Tags: maven, jenkins, dashboard, owasp, owasp-dependency-check

I have several projects using the OWASP's Dependency Check maven plugin. This is working perfectly for each. But I would like to merge all the project results in one dashboard, as I've got many projects...

I thought it was possible with "Dashboard View" (https://plugins.jenkins.io/dashboard-view) but I can't figure out how to use it.

Any clues ?

Best regards

Comment: StackOverflow is about helping people fix their programming code. Requests for undocumented case debugging, tutorials, research, tools, recommendations, libraries, and code are off-topic. Please read stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask, stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and take the tour (you'll also earn your first badge. Then click `edit` if you have a *specific* question about "Dashboard View" that you would like help with.

Answer (score 1):

You should achieve it when you collect all your reports in one place and run dependencyCheckPublisher.

For example when you have files:

```
reports/projectA/dependency-check-report.xml
reports/projectB/dependency-check-report.xml
```

and run in Jenkins:

```
dependencyCheckPublisher pattern: '**/dependency-check-report.xml'
```

then it should be merged into one dashboard

Comment: didn't work. I merged for 3 projects and in Jenkins 3 links for Dependency Check reports are coming and only for 1 project its showing result (header still combines result of all 3 projects but per assembly details are coming only for 1 project)

Comment: The problem is already reported: https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-58610